# Using aggregate on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame, which I need to use the aggregate function for one specific column which I am listing in the value. I am using pivot table from pandas for that.

```
 Sample ID  Type    Score   Freq
AE01    AAA Non 0.65    1
AE01    BBB IND 0.57    14
AE03    SAS IND 0.56    14
AE03    SAP IND 0.689   15
AE03    TCS IND 0.56    16
AE05    BBB IND 0.85    17
AE05    CTC IND 0.45    18
AE05    CTC Non 0.15    19
AE05    CTC Non 0.14    20
AE05    CTC Non 0.4678  21
```

The following is the script I used for that,

```
table_pat_rel = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID",'Type'],values=['Sample'],
               aggfunc={'Sample':np.size})
```

Give some following output,

```
ID  Type    Sample
AAA Non 1
BBB IND 2
SAS IND 1
SAP IND 1
TCS IND 1
CTC IND 5
```

But I am aiming following output,

```
ID  Recurrence  Sample
AAA 1   AE01
BBB 2   AE01 
        AE05
SAS 1   AE03
SAP 1   AE03
TCS 1   AE03
CTC 4   AE05
```

I tried with groupby as following

```
 df.drop_duplicates(['Sample', 'ID']).groupby(['ID','Sample']).size().sort_values(ascending=True).head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Score': [0.65, 0.57, 0.56, 0.689, 0.56, 0.85, 0.45, 0.15, 0.14, 0.4678], 
'ID': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'SAS', 'SAP', 'TCS', 'BBB', 'CTC', 'CTC', 'CTC', 'CTC'], 
'Sample': ['AE01', 'AE01', 'AE03', 'AE03', 'AE03', 'AE05', 'AE05', 'AE05', 'AE05', 'AE05'], 
'Freq': [1, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 
'Type': ['Non', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND', 'IND']},
columns=['Sample','ID','Type','Score','Freq'])
print (df)
  Sample   ID Type   Score  Freq
0   AE01  AAA  Non  0.6500     1
1   AE01  BBB  IND  0.5700    14
2   AE03  SAS  IND  0.5600    14
3   AE03  SAP  IND  0.6890    15
4   AE03  TCS  IND  0.5600    16
5   AE05  BBB  IND  0.8500    17
6   AE05  CTC  IND  0.4500    18
7   AE05  CTC  IND  0.1500    19
8   AE05  CTC  IND  0.1400    20
9   AE05  CTC  IND  0.4678    21

orig = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID",'Type'],values=['Sample'],
               aggfunc={'Sample':np.size})

print (orig)
          Sample
ID  Type        
AAA Non        1
BBB IND        2
CTC IND        4
SAP IND        1
SAS IND        1
TCS IND        1
```

I think you need swap `Sample` and `Type`, instead `values=['Sample']` use `values=['Freq']`, but it seems you can use some other columns not used for `index`, because use `aggfunc=len` (same as `aggfunc='size'`)

```
table_pat_rel1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID",'Sample'],values=['Freq'],aggfunc=len) \
                  .reset_index(level=1) \
                  .rename(columns={'Freq':'Recurrence'}) \
                  .set_index('Recurrence', append=True)
print (table_pat_rel1)
               Sample
ID  Recurrence       
AAA 1            AE01
BBB 1            AE01
    1            AE05
CTC 4            AE05
SAP 1            AE03
SAS 1            AE03
TCS 1            AE03
```

Or use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
table_pat_rel2 = df.groupby(['ID','Sample']) \
                   .size() \
                   .reset_index(level=1) \
                   .rename(columns={0:'Recurrence'}) \
                   .set_index('Recurrence', append=True)

print (table_pat_rel2)
               Sample
ID  Recurrence       
AAA 1            AE01
BBB 1            AE01
    1            AE05
CTC 4            AE05
SAP 1            AE03
SAS 1            AE03
TCS 1            AE03
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the solution, but I have edited my output could you please check it now

Comment: Thank you. Why is BBB  twice? Is it typo?

Comment: It seem one row witn BBB is missing.

Comment: I try edit answer by your sample `Dataframe`. Output is same, but in row with `BBB` is difference - double `1` vs `2`. If it is problem, can you explain more? Thank you.